# Adding data from KML/shapefile/GeoJSON to OSM nodes

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, geojson, kml

I have data of streets which is marked with the osm way/node ids. I would like to add speed limit data which is available in KML, shapefile, or GeoJSON to these OSM wayids (OSM wayid with start node and end node).

data.seattle.gov/Transportation/Seattle-Streets/jc8u-fewc

I was trying to convert the OSM map to KML (with ogr2ogr) but this failed in one way or another and now am experimenting with shapefiles.

How would you go about this problem?

I am new to map file formats I probably don't see the simple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To combine your street data with the speed limit data into a single file, you'll need to do a GIS operation called a "table join".  You can use something like QGIS to bring in your geometry dataset (streets), as well as your additional attributes table (speed limit). You'll essentially be adding a new column to the attribute table of your streets dataset, and populating it with the relevant speed limits numbers where the IDs match.

You can find a tutorial for this kind of operation here: 
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_table_joins.html